# Encode cipher class with bitwise operators

Tags: java, encode, bitwise-operators

How can I modify the following program so that it uses an eight-character string as the key?

```
public class SelfTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String msg = "This is a test";
        String encmsg = "";
        String decmsg = "";
        int key = 88;
        System.out.println("Original msg: " + msg);
        for(int i=0; i< msg.length(); i++){
            encmsg = encmsg + (char) (msg.charAt(i)^key);
        }
        System.out.println("Encode msg: " + encmsg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why exactly eight?

Comment: @Vallentinhis homework probably told him to use 8

Comment: yes it's my homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use each character in the key individually and wrap around it when it's done. E.g.:

```
for(int i=0; i< msg.length(); i++){
        encmsg = encmsg + 
                 (char) (msg.charAt(i) ^ (key.charAt(i % key.length())));
    }
```

Comment: I thought about using each character in the key individually but I couldn't figure out what order should I use these characters? Your suggestion helps! Thanks!